# How to create an online-offline application using servicestack

Tags: wpf, servicestack

I'm trying to figure out how to create an offline / online approch to use within a huge application.

Right now, each part of the application has its own model and datalayer, who directly read / write data from / to SQL.  My boss is asking me to create a kind of buffer that, in case of connectivity failure, might be used to store data until the connection to SQL return active.

What I'm trying to create is something like this: move all datalayers into a servicestack service.  Each "GET" method should query the database and store the result into a cache to be reused once the connection to SQL is not available.  Each "POST" and "PUT" method must execute their actions or store the request into a cache if the connection fail. this cache must be cleared once the connection to SQL is restored.

How can I achieve this?  Mine is a WPF application running on Windows 10.

Best regards
Enrico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintaining caches on the server is not going to help create an offline Application given the client wouldn't have access to the server in order to retrieve those caches. What you'd need instead is to maintain state on the client so in the event that network access is lost the client is loading from its own local caches.

Architecturally this is easiest achieved with a Web App using a Single Page App framework like [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) (+ Vuex) or [React](https://reactjs.org/) (+ Redux or MobX). The ServiceStack [TechStacks](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/TechStacks) and [Gistlyn](http://gistlyn.com/) Apps are good (well documented) examples of this where they store client state in a Vuex store (for TechStacks created in Vue) or Redux Store (for Gistlyn created in React), or the [Old TechStacks](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacks) (created with AngularJS).

For good examples of this checkout [Gistlyn's snapshots feature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Gistlyn#snapshots) where the entire client state can be restored from a single serialized JSON object or approach used the [Real Time Network Traveler example](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/typescript-redux#example-9---real-time-networked-time-traveller) where an initial client state and delta's can be serialized across the network to enable real-time remote control of multiple connected clients.

They weren't developed with offline in mind, but their architecture naturally leads to being offline capable, courtesy of each page being first loaded from its local store then it fires off a Request to update its local cache which thanks to the reactivity of JS SPA fx's, the page is automatically updated with the latest version of the server.

#### Messaging APIs

HTTP has synchronous tight coupling which isn't ideal for offline communication, what you want instead is to design your write APIs so they're One Way/Asynchronous so you can implement a message queue on the client which queues up Request DTOs and sends them reliably to the server by resending them (using an exponential backoff) until the succeed without error. Then for cases where the client needs to be notified that their request has been processed they can either be done via [Server Events](http://docs.servicestack.net/server-events) or via the client long-polling the server checking to see if their request has been processed.

Comment: I was wondering if having on each pc where the application is installed the servicestack service might be of any help.  The idea of the server events to notify the client is more or less like mine, except for using SignalR because of its backpane functionalities. Which kind of queue should I use to persist the request dto queue?  And what about a GET request instead?  Should I use the same queue as well?

Comment: @Enrico Server Events also has a [Redis Server Events](http://docs.servicestack.net/redis-server-events) that lets you scale out to multiple servers. You can use any C# Queue collection, i.e. even the `Queue<T>` class. My preference would probably be to use `BlockingCollection` and have it sent in a single background thread. The MQ only needed for writes, for GET's have them populate a local ViewModel state and the UI binded to the local state then have GET requests update same local state so that the UI is automatically updated when local state is modified.

Comment: I will look at that redis solution.  I abandon the idea of the local state in the viewmodel because I would like to have a not-only-in-memory storage so I thought at the cached service

Comment: @Enrico Don't see how it's possible to have an offline application without local state/cache. You can load that state from localStorage, e.g. Gistlyn saves it's local state to localStorage on each key press.

Comment: thanks a lot, in the next weeks I will create a poc with your suggestions.